# Google Sign In Account Type using Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent

Tags: android, google-signin, android-account

I've come across two ways of creating the intent for Google Sign In:

1.

```
private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}

private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult: " + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        String googleAccessToken = acct.getServerAuthCode();
        Uri thumbnailUrl = acct.getPhotoUrl();
        String firstName = acct.getGivenName();
        String lastName = acct.getFamilyName();
        ...
    }
}
```

2.

```
private void signIn() {
    Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null, new String[]{"com.google"},
            false, null, null, null, null);
    startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode,
                                final Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String accountName = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: " + accountName);
        String mEmail = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
        String mType = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE);
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: " + mType);
    }
}
```

Using the first way, I can get the user's account picture: Uri thumbnailUrl = acct.getPhotoUrl();

Using the second way, I can get the user's account type: String mType = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE);

I need the account type to get the access token:

```
Account account = new Account(mEmail, mType);
token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(SignInActivity.this, account, mScope);
```

I've been passing a hard-coded variable for mType ("com.google") which works but feels improper. Is there a way of getting the account type when using the Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent version of the intent?

Also, is there a way to get the account picture when using the AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent version of the intent?